# Typescript extend type of passed properties within nested function

Tags: typescript

I have created a function to build styles. The output is of type SxClasses, giving me typescript autocompletion of class names.

I augment passed properties (becoming ExtendedProps) using a nested function (wrapper).

```
type SxClasses<S> = { [className in keyof S]: SxProps<Theme> };
type ExtendedProps<P> = P & { themeVars: typeof ThemeVars };
type SxClassesWrapper<P, T> = (props: ExtendedProps<P>) => T;

export function makeStyles<P, C = SxClasses<S>>(wrapper: (props: P) => S): SxClassesWrapper<P, C> {
  return (props: P) => {
    const extendedProps: ExtendedProps<P> = {
      ...props,
      themeVars: ThemeVars,
    };
    return wrapper(extendedProps);
  };
}

// Example:
const classes = makeStyles<{ height: number }>((props) => ({
  class1: { width: '100px', borderRadius: props.themeVars.borderRadius },
  class2: { height: props.height }
}
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

The variable 'props' should be of type ExtendedProps
classes should be of type SxClasses

I don't understand how to pass the initial styles (S) within a nested function to build SxClasses as an output. It says that S can't be resolved in C = SxClasses.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your function definition is wrong in part of `C = SxClasses<S>`. `S` is not defined yet, but you already use it. It would be kinda faster if you provide the full code with all types

Comment: I added a link to edit it, thanks for your comment

Comment: TypeScript doesn't currently support *partial type argument inference*, so you need to use workarounds.  One such workaround is *currying*, shown [at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV4dGW).  Does that fully address your question?  If so, I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what `SxClasses` and `SxClassesWrapper` are doing here.  The function takes a callback of type `(p: ExtendedProps<P>) => S` and returns a function of type `(p: P) => S`. If I give it those types, it looks fine, as shown [in this link](//tsplay.dev/WoanPN). (It still uses currying). Does *that* version work? If so, then please [edit] the code in your question to be a [mre] without `SxClasses` and `SxClassesWrapper`. If not, then you might still want to [edit] to be clear about what they are doing (especially the `any` bit, which just throws away information about `S`).

Answer (score 0):

Made a little bit refactoring of your code. Actually I couldn't make `themeVars` implicit in `makeStyles`, so you should pass `themeVars` everywhere you call `classes`, but it is a good pattern and is great to test:

```js
type ThemeVars = {
  color: string;
  borderRadius: string;
}

const themeVars: ThemeVars = { color: 'blue', borderRadius: '4' }

type SxClasses = { [className: string]: Record<string, unknown> };
type ExtendedProps<P> = P & { themeVars: ThemeVars };
type SxClassesWrapper<P, T> = (props: ExtendedProps<P>) => T;

function makeStyles<P, C = SxClasses>(wrapper: (props: ExtendedProps<P>) => C): SxClassesWrapper<P, C> {
  return (props: P) => {
    const extendedProps = {
      ...props,
      themeVars,
    };
    return wrapper(extendedProps);
  };
}

// Example:
const classes = makeStyles<{ height: number }>((props) => ({
  class1: { width: '100px', borderRadius: props.themeVars.borderRadius },
  class2: { height: props.height }
}))

console.log(classes({ height: 100, themeVars }))
```

Comment: I would like to retain the autocompletion of classnames, for example classes({ height: 100, themeVars }).class1 should be suggested. But for that we need to get the value down to SxClasses type

Comment: Currently it seems to me the only way is to explicitly define the type of the returned object.